# chart.js pie chart not playing nicely with small numbers

Tags: chart.js

It seems chart.js pie chart needs numbers larger than 1 or 2 to complete a full pie.  When I have small values passed it only renders a small sliver of the pie chart, instead of a full pie. (albeit, the chart is still accurate in its own right).

Is there a fix to this?  Have I missed the boat on something?

My use is to display the number of tasks each user has in a project.  Sometimes that number is very small - ie. 1.  When larger numbers are passed it works perfectly.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Note: $row[0] is an integer (in this 
case it may be small numbers. ie: 1)

```
$cnt=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $pieData[] = array('value' => $row[0],
                       'color' => $piesectioncolor[$cnt],
                       'highlight' => '#aaaaaa',
                       'label' => ucfirst($row[2])." . ucfirst($row[3]));                                   
                       $cnt++;
}   

<script>
var pieData = <? echo json_encode($pieData); ?>;

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've got so far?

Comment: Even better than the code can you add it in a jsfiddle

Comment: I put the code up.  Thanks.